# MIME type and extension for native blackberry10 app

Tags: php, http-headers, blackberry-10, mobile-application

I am building a custom file provider in php that will allow the user to download apps based on the pre-selected OS (android, ios...).

It's the same app but i have a different version depending on the OS of the mobile.

This is what i have for Android based on wikipedia :

> **APK** files are zip format packages based on the JAR file format, with .apk as the filename extension. The MIME type associated with APK files is **application/vnd.android.package-archive**

Is there something similar for Blackberry10 native apps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no MIME type for Blackberry 10 apps.  Unlike APK files for Android, or COD/JAD files for Blackberry 7 and earlier, Blackberry 10 BAR files cannot be installed by simply downloading and opening them (ie Over-The-Air installs).  They can only be installed via AppWorld, or by putting a BB10 device in developer mode and using a sideloading tool.  Thus, the only appropriate MIME type to use would be `application/octet-stream` to download the BAR as-is to a local file so it can then be sideloaded separately.

Comment: Thanks Gambit (@Remy). I suppose they have a good reason to do that. Now i know why their is no documentation on the .bar